# How to show Html label in Highlight.js?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I want to show text with < p>Hello World ! < /p>  int ? 
 but it is showing that under

```
<pre>

<code >

    <p>Hello World ! </p>

</code>

</pre>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can using append() in JQUERY . but its to hard to match specific language in highlight js.

but you better using attr to get manualy what the code your'e using.

i have simple code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var e = $("pre code"),
      l = "<p class='windowLabel'>Hello World !</p>",
    i = { border: 'solid 1px #222',background: '#222',display: 'inline-block',height: 'auto',padding: '0', lineHeight: '1.375rem',position: 'absolute',margin: '-6px 9px',top: 'auto',right: '2px',textAlign: 'center',textTransform: 'uppercase',fontSize: '13px',color: '#fff',borderRadius: '3px',zIndex: '30', opacity: '.8',transition: 'all .5s ease-in'};
    e.append(l);
   $("p.windowLabel").css(i);
});
```